# LINQ - Sort List of objects using OrderBy EnumValue, and Union result set?

Tags: c#, linq, linq-to-objects

Greetings!  I want to use LINQ to query a list of objects and sort them by an enumeration value, string value then union the rest of the list sorted in a similar fashion  LINQ newbie here, so be gentle.

```
//CTOR for my class
MyClass(id, "Name Value Here", Enum.EnumValueHere);
```

I create a list of these objects and want to variably sort them such that all items with Enum.EnumValue[X] are shown first in the list, sorted by Name, followed by all other items sorted in a similar fashion (almnost like a Union of result sets in SQL)

```
//What I have so far (only sorts the list)
List<MyClass> = (from s in MyClass orderby s.EnumValue, s.NameValue  select s).ToList();
```

Any Guru's out there have some LINQ Magic to share?

Thanks!

Comment: SQL only allows one ORDER BY per query, so think order the entire set not each UNION section.  There are tricks to sort each section of the UNION differently, but I don't think that is what you are asking.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Not sure exactly what you mean, but could you use something like this?

```
// Using Color as enum just to make things clearer
class ClassyClass
{
    public string Name {get; private set;}
    public Color Color {get; private set;}
    public ClassyClass(id, string name, Color color) { ... }
}


var orderedList = collectionOfClassyClasses
            .OrderBy(x => x.Color != Color.Red) // False comes before true
            .ThenBy(x => x.Color)
            .ThenBy(x => x.Name)
            .ToList();
```

If `collectionOfClassyClasses` was some sort of collection of `ClassyClass` objects, then `orderedList` would be ordered so that all those with Color set to Red would come first, ordered by name, and then all the others ordered by color and then name. At least I think it would... haven't tested it :p Let me know if it doesn't, hehe.

Comment: Thank's for your response.  Your edit proved to be correct, in that false is evaluated b4 true...your solution works great, thanks a ton!

Comment: Great to hear it worked out :) I'll remove the edit and fix the code so that it is correct instead =)

Answer (score 0):

You could take the first list and do a list.AddRange() which takes an ienumerable.